# Pass PHP variables to external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have 3 files; 1.html, 2.js, 3.php

I'm trying to get the value of a variable in 3.php to update in an element in 1.html

In 3.php I have a variable `$title`

In 2.js I'm trying:

```
var titlePHP = <?php echo json_encode ($title); ?>;
            console.log(titlePHP);
            $('#productTitle').val(titlePHP);
```

But getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

I've tried the 3 solutions in [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) but they only seem to work if all the code is on the same page, but my code has to be seperate because these files are doing extra things.

I can update a single DOM element using `echo` in php, but I need to pass multiple variables across, so echo is insufficient.

Is there a better solution to my problem? Thanks

edit:

2.js:

```
$(function() {

    //Get the ASIN input
    var form = $('#inputASIN');

    //Get the div to update
    var formReply = $('#formReply'); //status

    //event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //serialise the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        //submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $(formReply).toggleClass('card-footer bg-success text-white');
            $(formReply).text(response);

            $('#asinForm').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $(formReply).toggleClass('card-footer bg-danger text-white');

            // Set the message text.
            if (data.responseText !== '') {
                $(formReply).text(data.responseText);
            } else {
                $(formReply).text('Error: could not load data from API.');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

3.php:

```
    <?php

      if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            include("amazonApiClass.php");
            $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();
            $asin = $_POST["ASIN"];

            if (empty($asin)) {
                  echo "Error: Please enter an ASIN!";
                  exit;
            }

            //fetch product information with the object
            try {
                  $result = $obj->getItemByAsin($asin);
                  echo "Success! Move on to step 2.";
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                  echo $e->getMessage();
            }



            $title = $result->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title;
            $price = $result->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice;    


            echo "Title: $title<br />";
            echo "Price: $price<br />";

      } else {
        echo "Error: could not load data from API.";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX from 2.js to get the variable from 3.php.

Comment: Where is `2.js` included? In `1.html` or `3.php`? What is the relationship between `1.html` and `3.php` anyway? Please describe how your application is structured

Comment: From the linked question, the top voted answer's first option is to use AJAX but it doesn't sound like you've tried that at all. That certainly doesn't require _"all the code is on the same page"_

Comment: If you disagree with the duplicate vote, please update your question with the any attempts you made based on the other answers

Comment: @Phil 2.js is included in 1.html. Basically 1.html is a form that takes an input and sends it to 3.php to query an API. 2.js is a middleman to stop the page redirecting and it updates elements on 1.html

I tried the AJAX answer from the other SO I linked, but I could not get it to work.

Comment: Right, so sounds like you want `2.js` to make an AJAX request to `3.php` (triggered by an event in `1.html`) and then use the response to make changes on `1.html`. This scenario is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23740549/283366)

Answer (score -1):

You can't add PHP code into an **external** (`.js`) JavaScript file, as JavaScript itself has no knowledge of how PHP works. You also can't make use of `1.html`, as HTML doesn't know how PHP works either.

What you're probably looking to do is make use of **inline** JavaScript on `3.php` (or another `.php` page):

```
<?php
  $title = "Title";
?>
<script>
  var titlePHP = <?php echo $title; ?>
<script>
```

Unlike with trying to output the PHP directly into the JavaScript file, this **will** work. Your PHP file will see `<?php`, and swap to PHP to inject its variable on page load, then see `?>` and swap back to JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var titlePHP = "Title";
<script>
```

Comment: It's unlikely `$title` contains quote characters so you'd be better off with `<?= json_encode($title) ?>`

Comment: As its likely text I would suggest some quotes like `var titlePHP = "<?php echo $title; ?>";`

Comment: @RiggsFolly the best way to make a PHP variable safe for use in JS is `json_encode()`

Comment: This gives me an error of `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in admin\php\apiCall.php on line 59`